# Nested entry in mongodb, sum and average only over max of a subfield

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo, nosql-aggregation

I have a db which contains documents, i.e.:

```
{ id: "first_document", document: [
{page: 1, content: "text"},
{page: 2, content: "text"},
{page: 3, content: "text"}]}, 

{ id: "second_document", document: [
{page: 1, content: "text"}, 
{page: 2, content: "text"}]}
```

and so on, with multiple documents of various sizes.

I need to find the average and the total number of pages across all documents.

I have done a few tries with different pipelines but can't seem to find the solution. Example of a basic test I did:

```
[{ "$unwind": "$document" }, 
{ "$group":{"_id": None,"average_pages": {"$avg" : "$document.page"}}}]
```

but this of course makes the average (and the sum) across all entries.

How do I make the average and sum only over the maximum page number? (in the example provided, the avg and the sum only between 3 and 2).

Expected output for this example:

avg = 2.5

sum = 5

Comment: Could you show the expected output as well

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
collection.aggregate([
{
 "$unwind": {
           path:"$document" ,
           preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true
     } 
},
{
$group:{
    _id:"$_id",
    totalPage:{$sum:1},
    average:{$avg:"$document.page"}

    }
}
])
```